# Android - Server-client

Tags: android

I am working on a multiplayer game for android. It is location based so I anticipate the need for a client-server architecture with a central server, and therefore I am currently looking at how Android could communicate with such a server.

The server should grant the client access to gps information - where stuff are on a map, and the client would send information back to the server when catching the stuff (so that it can make the stuff disapear from the map)

I om really lost how to structure this. How do I get the server-client to work with android, an how do I build this server-client?

Answer (score 0):

With web services.
You could use ksoap-2 on the android-client side. And write your web services in C# as an ASP.NET application that you can host with Mono 2.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

For communication on device you can use `HTTPRequest`, or `Socket`. Information about using it you can find in [this docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/package-summary.html).

For server-side the simplest way is to create javaSE application, and realize simple communication between server and device.